# Cant find NinjectWebCommon in asp.net Web API Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I am creating an asp.net web api project. I am using Ninject for dependency resolver. I am adding [Ninject.Web.WebAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi) from nuget. But I don't find any NinjectWebCommon.cs in my App_Start folder

Do i need to install any aditional package??

Answer (score 0):

Install `Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost` if you are hosting the WebApi project via IIS - this will create `NinjectWebCommon.cs`.

See the wiki for more info on different types of WebApi projects. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/wiki/Setting-up-an-mvc-webapi-application