# Ninject & WebAPI: Getting started after install from NuGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, nuget

I installed the NuGet package *[Ninject Integration for WebApi2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/)* via the Package Manager Console.

According to the [wiki on the project's GitHub pages](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-an-IIS-hosted-web-application), this should have created a class called `NinjectWebCommon` in the App_Start folder. But it didn't.

That same GitHub wiki page explains what you *should* see so that you can add it yourself. So I tried creating the `NinjectWebCommon` class myself. The problem here is that I can't find the namespace for `OnePerRequestModule` in the following snippet.

```
public static void Start()
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
```

The alternative, and according to that GitHub wiki page there's no effective difference between the two, is to modify the global.asax. So I tried this method and added some bindings like so

```
private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IEntityAccess>().To<EntityAccess>();
    kernel.Bind<IDictionaryRepository>().To<DictionaryRepository>();
}
```

and found that my project builds, but when a request is sent to the WebAPI project it can't be found (*i.e.*, I receive a 404 response).

So there's obviously some other piece of necessary wiring up which isn't in my project.

It appears that despite changing my `global.asax` to derive from `NinjectHttpApplication`, the `global.asax` is no longer being called.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing? I've uninstalled and reinstalled the NuGet package a few times but the `NinjectWebCommon` class never appears, nor does my global.asax file ever get modified.

I've also read [Ninject's own documentation](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html) but frustratingly this is a fairly large tutorial covering the basics of IoC and how Ninject operates rather than telling you how to get started with using Ninject.

There's also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285736/cant-find-ninjectwebcommon-in-asp-net-web-api-project) asking how to get started with Ninject for WebAPI, so it looks like something's amiss with their NuGet package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And like that, I've just found the answer: there is an additional NuGet package which must be referenced:

> Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost

Installing "Ninject integration for WebApi2" package is not sufficient.

This really should be more clearly explained.